# Arrange data retrieved by database in a HTML table using foreach

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using codeigniter.  I pass data retrieved by the database to my view. There are 5 lists I must display on a table each column should contain list of names generated by foreach loop in the view. Following is my code of the view.

```
 <table class="table table-hover" >
    <thead>
    <tr>
      <th scope="col" width="20%">Cameramen</th>
      <th scope="col" width="30%">Camera Assistants</th>
      <th scope="col" width="12%">Technical Assistants</th>
      <th scope="col" width="20%">Setup Engineer</th>
      <th scope="col" width="30%">Audio Operator</th>
      <th scope="col" width="12%">Vision Operator</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>


    <tbody>
      <tr>
       <?php
        $index = 0;
        foreach($c_list as $n_key){?>

           <td><?php echo $index+1; ?>
            <?php echo $n_key->name; ?><br/><br/>
             <?php 
              $index++;
              }?>  
            </td>

        <?php
          $index = 0;
          foreach($ca_list as $n_key){?>
            <td><?php echo $index+1; ?>
              <?php echo $n_key->name; ?><br/><br/>
              <?php 
              $index++;
              }?>  
            </td>

          <?php
            $index = 0;
              foreach($ta_list as $n_key){?>
               <td><?php echo $index+1; ?>
                <?php echo $n_key->name; ?><br/><br/>
                 <?php 
                  $index++;
                  }?>  
                </td>


            <?php
              $index = 0;
              foreach($se_list as $n_key){?>
                <td><?php echo $index+1; ?>
                <?php echo $n_key->name; ?><br/><br/>
                 <?php 
                  $index++;
                  }?>  
                </td>

            <?php
              $index = 0;
              foreach($ao_list as $n_key){?>
                <td><?php echo $index+1; ?>
                  <?php echo $n_key->name; ?><br/><br/>
                  <?php 
                  $index++;
                  }?>  
                </td>

              <?php
                $index = 0;
                  foreach($vo_list as $n_key){?>
                    <td><?php echo $index+1; ?>
                    <?php echo $n_key->name; ?><br/><br/>
                     <?php 
                      $index++;
                      }?>  
                    </td>

            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
```

But it gives the following out put.

[image]

I want to display the names line by line in each column.  Can anyone show me the error?

To retrieve the data from database I have written 6 function in my model. They almost same. I add one model function here.

```
public function get_c_names($c)
{
    $cdata = array();
    foreach($c as $row) {
        $cdata[] = $row->employee_id;
    }

    $this->db->select('employee.name');
    $this->db->from('employee');
    $this->db->where('employee.id IN ('.implode(", ",$cdata).')');
    $query=$this->db->get();
    return $query->result();
}
```

In controller I call this function by the following code and then it is passed to view as follows. All 6 functions have same pattern. So I post only 1 of them.

```
 $name['c_list']  = $this->employee_model->get_c_names($c);
 $this->load->view('team_view',$name);
```

Comment: If you show us what is in each of these `$??_list` arrays, then someone may be able to help you. If not we are kinda working in the dark, and all you will get are **guesses** I think we can guess what is in them but its better if you actually tell us

Comment: If these arrays are built by querying the database, you could also show us that code, as it is most likely the solution would be to do that part in a better way

Comment: @RiggsFolly  I have updated the answer. please check it.

Comment: Will need your schema. I would bet there is a way of building one query to generate all these X arrays with all contents on one row for each row of your table

Answer (score 1):

```
<table class="table table-hover" >
<thead>
<tr>
   <th scope="col" width="20%">Cameramen</th>
   <th scope="col" width="30%">Camera Assistants</th>
   <th scope="col" width="12%">Technical Assistants</th>
   <th scope="col" width="20%">Setup Engineer</th>
   <th scope="col" width="30%">Audio Operator</th>
   <th scope="col" width="12%">Vision Operator</th>
</tr>
</thead>


<tbody>


<?php

// find the longest array
$max = max(count($c_list), count($ca_list), count($ta_list), count($se_list), count($ao_list), count($vo_list));

for($x = 0 ; $x < $max ; $x++){
    echo '<tr>';
      echo '<td>'. (isset($c_list[$x])?$c_list[$x]:'') .'</td>';
      echo '<td>'. (isset($ca_list[$x])?$ca_list[$x]:'') .'</td>';
      echo '<td>'. (isset($ta_list[$x])?$ta_list[$x]:'') .'</td>';
      echo '<td>'. (isset($se_list[$x])?$se_list[$x]:'') .'</td>';
      echo '<td>'. (isset($ao_list[$x])?$ao_list[$x]:'') .'</td>';
      echo '<td>'. (isset($vo_list[$x])?$vo_list[$x]:'') .'</td>';
    echo '</tr>';
}

?>

  </tbody>
</table>
```

This work's with multiple lengths arrays.

Answer (score 0):

```
<table class="table table-hover" >
<thead>
<tr>
  <th scope="col" width="20%">Cameramen</th>
  <th scope="col" width="30%">Camera Assistants</th>
  <th scope="col" width="12%">Technical Assistants</th>
  <th scope="col" width="20%">Setup Engineer</th>
  <th scope="col" width="30%">Audio Operator</th>
  <th scope="col" width="12%">Vision Operator</th>
</tr>
</thead>


<tbody>


  <?php
    for($x = 0 ; $x < count($c_list) ; $x++){
        echo '<tr>';
          echo '<td>'. $c_list[$x] .'</td>';
          echo '<td>'. $ca_list[$x] .'</td>';
          echo '<td>'. $ta_list[$x] .'</td>';
          echo '<td>'. $se_list[$x] .'</td>';
          echo '<td>'. $ao_list[$x] .'</td>';
          echo '<td>'. $vo_list[$x] .'</td>';
        echo '</tr>';
    }

  ?>

      </tbody>
    </table>
```

If all the lists have the same length this is a solution.